# Github - Directory in one repo as a separate repo

Tags: git, github

I want to use only one directory of a certain repo as a separate repo in my project. In such a way that when this folder gets updates I get them also.

I wonder if this is even possible with Github? I was not able to google something that solves this for me.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/9210961)